# Reason Angular Material Modal need to be components?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was wondering if there is a good reason Angular Material Modals/Dialogs need to be made as a component, added to a module and also be an entry component to be used.

It all seems like overkill to just have a sleek dialog open. 
Is there a particular reason its not like a directive I could just put into html and just make it show based on a condition? That seems like a straightforward approach but maybe someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a large component with a large payload it's better to load it dynamically:

- to avoid the initial payload loading, by letting you app load and load the other dynamic components later when needed
- the other benefit is unit testing, you can test it separately
- it can be reused in many places in your app

but if you have a very simple dialog there is no need to create a dynamic component for that.

Comment: Do you have any documentation or links to create a simple dialog with material, without the step of creating a component?